# Syntax error in bash script : Invalid Arithmetic Operator in sed command

Tags: bash, sed

**Script:**

```
#!/bin/bash

line_num=349

pattern_2="$(sed -n "${line_num}p" ssg_ds_5%.csv | awk 'BEGIN {FS= ","}; {print $9}')"

echo "$pattern_2"
```

**Error:**

```
")syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "209
'ed: -e expression #1, char 4: unknown command: `
```

The sed command is supposed to run in a loop and extract one line from a csv file. It works fine when I give the command from the terminal, but when I run the script, I receive this error.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
TIA

Comment: You should remove the wrapping double quotes in the main line -- they are not needed.

Comment: The error message seems messy, are Windows end-of-lines involved?

Comment: Try `"$(tr '\r' '\n'<ssg_ds_5%.csv | sed -n "${line_num}p"  |...`

Comment: Yes, there were end of lines involved `^M` present in the data. Missed those somehow. Thanks a lot. I added the `-d` option to `tr`: `"$(tr -d '\r' '\n' < ssg_ds_5%.csv | sed -n "${line_num}p" |...`